# Run code every "x" seconds without setInterval

Tags: javascript, cinnamon

I'm writing a Cinnamon panel applet (in JavaScript) that polls a set command for information every 20-120 seconds, set by the user. But the problem is that `setInterval` does not exist in the subset (?) of JavaScript that Cinnamon applets use. I tried to use this:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
      currentDate = Date.now();
    } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}
```

This doesn't work, as it locks up the whole panel for `milliseconds` except for a moment while it's running.

```
while (true) {
    sleep(seconds*1000)
    this.set_applet_label(cmd_output)
}
```

This is the code for the loop I'm using.
**What I need is some kind of non-blocking way to run code every X seconds in JavaScript.**

Comment: Try [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Comment: It looks like you can access a Timeout function by importing `mainloop`: https://github.com/axos88/cinnamon-countdown-timer/blob/master/applet.js#L213

Comment: Doesn't the Cinnamon applet API provide something? `setInterval` is part of the DOM API. I'd think they'd have their own method.

Comment: @slappy You'd think it would, but I don't see any documentation for it anywhere.

Comment: @kel5isgod Until today, I had never heard of Cinnamon, or applets  I just did a Google Search, and found this, but I don't feel confortable enough posting an answer. Feel free to post the answer yourself if you can add details, and accept it so it can help future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered by @blex
By importing Mainloop, you can get a timeout_add_seconds function: https://github.com/axos88/cinnamon-countdown-timer/blob/master/applet.js#L213